# Windows 08 R2 Backup : create task template

Tags: backup, command-line-interface, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

it is possible to create a backup template or somehow configure backup shedule besides regular daily backup to local disk. I want to backup whole system every sunday to shared network folder. I must do it manually with "Backup once" in Windows Server Backup Console.

I looked into task scheduler and daily backup task is executed with templateId, like this:

```
wbadmin.exe start backup -templateId:{b217544a-00d6-4358-a8dd-ee14b82574f7} -quiet
```

It is possible to create another template with another setting?

I'm using windows server 2008 r2 standart.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are no native cmdlets to allow you manage Scheduled tasks on windows machine, however you can use powershell as a wrapper to the schtasks.exe command. Funnily enough I am running my wrapper script as I type this...

sctasks.exe will do all sorts of things - add, delete, modify, view scheduled tasks - I won't go into it here, there plenty of info out there :) just modify the command appropriately.

example code:

```
$listofServers = get-content "MyServers.txt"
foreach ($server in $listofServers) {
   $output = schtasks.exe /query /fo CSV /v /s $server
   write-output $output
   }
```

*edit* I forgot to add that then you can have a CSV or JOB file etc you can use as your template, and then use schtasks.exe to push it out to servers.